# Can I configure Grafana not to need passwords for users, without using anonymous login?

Tags: grafana

We use Grafana with the built-in authentication. We have multiple users so they can have their own preferences but it would be convenient if they didn't need to set passwords.

I know Grafana supports anonymous login but I want distinct users... who don't need passwords. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Configure Grafana with Auth Proxy](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/auth-proxy/) to let a HTTP reverse proxy handle authentication. And it is up to you how do you create "authentication" on the proxy - e.g. initial login screen (without password), which will save username into cookie and then proxy will use that value for the Grafana user definition in the request header (only your imagination is your limit and this only an idea - proxy implementation is not in the scope of this question here).

But for user convenience are Single Sign-On (SSO) protocols used usually. Grafana supports [Open ID Connect](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/) and paid version also [SAML](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/saml/). That's should be used in the serious nd secure implementation. One user login, which can be used then in many apps, which support SSO.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but this is a fully isolated (no internet) setup - does that raise any problems for easy SSO config? I haven't much time allocated (or IT approval) to be doing big changes ;)

Comment: @Mr.Boy You will need identity provider (IDP) server for SSO. You can use SaaS solutions (e.g. Azure, GCP, Auth0, Ping, Okta, ...) where you will need internet access, but nobody is stoping you to have own IDP (Keycloak, ...) in your network.

Comment: Hmm, this might be beyond our scope right now but something I can propose.